# Length of the first line of text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I were to load a block of text into a variable, I want to calculate the width of the first line. Here is the value of a block of text sitting in a variable that I'm trying to work with:

> ```
> Wine comes in at the mouth
> And love comes in at the eye;
> That's all we shall know for truth
> Before we grow old and die.
> I lift the glass to my mouth,
> I look at you, and I sigh.
> --W.B. Yeats
> ```

The result should be 26. How might I grab that first line's length?

Comment: Why don't you start by putting it into a variable, and then telling us where you get stuck?

Comment: `text.split('\n')[0].length` (not even worth posting as an answer)

Comment: I tried `console.log(poem.indexOf('\n');` but that didn't seem to work and it returned an error that I can't call indexOf on undefined. Hmmm I may have a deeper problem here.

Comment: @user3080991: If you get the error that you can call a method on undefined, it means that the variable that you use doesn't contain the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index of the first line break, that will be the length of the first line:

```
var len = text.indexOf('\n');
```